# Google account linking existing example

Tags: oauth-2.0, account, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I implemented a simple API.ai bot and I wanted to add it to google home platform but I really need help for the linking account part.

I don't understand if I need to implement an oauth2 protocol for my service or not. Is there any exemple or framework that allow implement this linking account step (any language is ok, it's just for a simple POC).

My goal is to ask my bot some informations and send him some orders to achieve simple processing on a server.

Hope that someone can help me, add a simple bot to google home to access and modify some informations in a server isn't really easy for me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Leon noted, you will need to implement the OAuth2 server yourself. The [Actions on Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) give details about what they are expecting and what steps you can do to implement it yourself. The [Authorization Code flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) is slightly preferred (additional features from the Assistant will require it in the future), but you're also allowed to use the https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow if you wish since it is slightly easier.

There are several packages that are out there that allow you to provide OAuth2, but require you to build the connection to your own account database. I've seen packages for .NET and JavaScript, but it shouldn't be too difficult to find one that meets your needs or to write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, finally succeed to make my OAuth2 server with Jhipster and it's working pretty well :)
Do you know when actions on google will be available for Pixels (and every Android 6.0+ device with Google Assistant) ? :) 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the answer was helpful, either accepting it or voting it up are appreciated. For new questions, it would be best to either open up a new StackOverflow question if it is coding related, or ask on the community at https://plus.google.com/communities/105684267327487893574

Comment: Well... disappointing that they broke links like that. But I've fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to authenticate the user, then you will need your own OAuth server. How to hook that up to an action is described in the docs: https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/account-linking

If however, this is just a personal project and you want to test it on your own device, then account linking is not necessary for you to get the action to work. You simply need to hook up your server logic to the action fulfillment. We recommend that you use the API.AI Actions integration. The docs cover how to do that: https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/apiai/dialogs-and-fulfillment

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I need my own OAuth server. Do you have any advice on how to implement it ? (an existing framework or an advice for the language to use ?)
I looked around and haven't find an "easy" way to implement my own Oauth2 server :/
I found Firebase but it seems that I can't implement a "custom" Oauth authentication that respond to Actions on Google specifi request and parameters (tell me if I'm wrong)
Last question: do I have to necessary use the implicit or authorization code flows ?